# Python 3 UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d

Tags: python, unicode

I want to make search engine and I follow tutorial in some web. 
I want to test parse html

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def parse_html(filename):
    """Extract the Author, Title and Text from a HTML file
    which was produced by pdftotext with the option -htmlmeta."""
    with open(filename) as infile:
        html = BeautifulSoup(infile, "html.parser", from_encoding='utf-8')
        d = {'text': html.pre.text}
        if html.title is not None:
            d['title'] = html.title.text
        for meta in html.findAll('meta'):
            try:
                if meta['name'] in ('Author', 'Title'):
                    d[meta['name'].lower()] = meta['content']
            except KeyError:
                continue
        return d

parse_html("C:\\pdf\\pydf\\data\\muellner2011.html")
```

and it getting error

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 867: character maps to <undefined>enter code here
```

I saw some solutions on the Web using the encode(). But I don't know how to insert encode() function in code. Can anyone help me?

Comment: What is the **full** traceback of the exception?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

In Python 3, files are opened as text (decoded to Unicode) for you; you don't need to tell BeautifulSoup what codec to decode from.

If decoding of the data fails, that's because you didn't tell the `open()` call what codec to use when reading the file; add the correct codec with an `encoding` argument:

```
with open(filename, encoding='utf8') as infile:
    html = BeautifulSoup(infile, "html.parser")
```

otherwise the file will be opened with your system default codec, which is OS dependent.

Comment: You can also add errors='ignore' to open(), in case you are not sure the file is 'utf-8' and you want to skip non-utf8 bytes, avoiding "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte" errors.  From here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56453782/utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xe2-invalid-continuation-byte-error

Comment: @Altair7852 that’s... a risky option that only works if your input is some other ASCII superset codec.

Comment: @Altair7852 the post you link to is specifically about reading a *PDF file*, which isn’t even a text file but a *binary format*. Opening it as text is the wrong thing to do.

Comment: Martijn Pieters you are correct, the linked post is not very relevant here, except for the flag, and yes - only use it when you know whare you are doing. In defence, I had the utf8 issues popping up when reading html files, thus the comment.

Comment: I am getting the same error because my configuration file contained few Chinese latter. I added 'utf-8' encoding in side config read function. Here is the code below. config.read('../conf/PM_AutomaticTariffUpload_Converter.conf',encoding = 'utf8')