# Reading file in python using csvreader

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to use one csv file using csv.reader and facing issue in decoding unicode character, tried all possible ways. here is my code-

```
 def get_input_dup(path):
            with open(path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
                reader = csv.reader(f)
                sentence_pairs = list(reader)
            #print(data)
            return sentence_pairs
```

this is the error message "return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 16: character maps to "
any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you on Python 2 or 3?

Comment: @burhanKhalid I'm using python 3.4.

Comment: try using pandas.read_csv(). it handles most data well

Comment: are you sure about Python 3.4? Are you sure your file is actually utf-8 and not something else?

Comment: Are you sure that the file from which you are reading is encoded as utf-8 rather than something else? I've had issues with files encoded as e.g. latin or with a BOM.

Comment: @maxpower tried using pandas also but didn't work for me,

Comment: @burhankhalid No, i'm not sure about the encoding type. I want to implement generic approach to read the file.

Comment: @timGJ I tried latin also, but I didn't get the output, got null object error, that i handled but the data was not same as file data.

Comment: this question title and code looks like yours. is the answer here helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30750843/python-3-unicodedecodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x9d