# UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 6554: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python

I am new to python and I am stuck I writing a code for printing any specific rows from the CSV file.
The CSV file contains the below data in tabular format. 3 rows are shared for reference below(total data has 180 rows):

```
Case Number Case Title  Closed Date Yearmonth Closed    Owner Email Owner   Case Status Priority    Customer Name   Country Name    Created On  Created Yearmonth   Resolution time Greater than 50 Greater than 30
CAS-100828-Q5Z8 YYYY    04-09-2018  201804  ABC@ABC.COM abc Resolved    Major   Z-ESDE-RD-ER    IN  02-05-2018  201802  62.97109954 Yes Yes
CAS-103690-Z2Q9 XXXX    4/13/2018   201804  xyz@ABC.COM xyz Resolved    Major   Z-DERF-DSE-SS   JP  2/14/2018   201802  57.86796296 Yes Yes
CAS-105359-G9V1 ZZZZ    04-03-2018  201804  wxv@ABC.COM wxv Resolved    Minor   Z-EDRF-RDS-ED   PO  2/20/2018   201802  41.92416667 No  Yes
```

I wanted to list the data which has a any specific value in any of the columns(eg if 'year month' close value is 201804 then it is printed else not.) and the next step was to print the data for any specific resolution time(say greater than 10 days)

The code I have tried is given below along with the error.
Please help in correcting me and tell the the way code should be written

```
import csv

with open("data1.csv", 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    rows = [row for row in reader if row['Yearmonth Closed'] == '201804']

for row in rows:
    print (row)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-49-6d59c793d8ac> in <module>()
      3 with open("data1.csv", 'r') as f:
      4     reader = csv.DictReader(f)
----> 5     rows = [row for row in reader if row['Yearmonth Closed'] == '201804']
      6 
      7 for row in rows:

<ipython-input-49-6d59c793d8ac> in <listcomp>(.0)
      3 with open("data1.csv", 'r') as f:
      4     reader = csv.DictReader(f)
----> 5     rows = [row for row in reader if row['Yearmonth Closed'] == '201804']
      6 
      7 for row in rows:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3-1\lib\csv.py in __next__(self)
    109         if self.line_num == 0:
    110             # Used only for its side effect.
--> 111             self.fieldnames
    112         row = next(self.reader)
    113         self.line_num = self.reader.line_num

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3-1\lib\csv.py in fieldnames(self)
     96         if self._fieldnames is None:
     97             try:
---> 98                 self._fieldnames = next(self.reader)
     99             except StopIteration:
    100                 pass

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3-1\lib\encodings\cp1252.py in decode(self, input, final)
     21 class IncrementalDecoder(codecs.IncrementalDecoder):
     22     def decode(self, input, final=False):
---> 23         return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
     24 
     25 class StreamWriter(Codec,codecs.StreamWriter):

UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 6554: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python 3 UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30750843/python-3-unicodedecodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x9d)

Comment: thanks @snakecharmerb it works, but it prints the below line  :: OrderedDict([('\ufeffCase Number', 'CAS-100828-Q5Z8'), ('Closed Date', '04-09-2018'), ('Yearmonth Closed', '201804'), ('Owner', 'Singh, Rupinder 2. (EXT - IN/Noida)'), ('Case Status', 'Resolved'), ('Priority', 'Major'), ('Customer Name', 'KDDI Corporation'), ('Country Name', 'Japan'), ('Created On', '02-05-2018'), ('Created Yearmonth', '201802'), ('Resolution time', '62.97109954')]) ----- at strat of every line it prints" OrderedDict([('\ufeff" before the line contents.

Comment: It''s a byte order mark - try setting the encoding as 'utf-8-sig'

Comment: thanks a lot, it worked