# Got stuck while reading files

Tags: python, file, unicode, character-encoding

**what Code DO's**

I am trying to read each file from the folder which i have given ,And extracting some line using bs4 Soup package in python.

I got an error reading the file that some unicode chars not able to read.

**error**

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:-----\check.py", line 25, in 
>       soup=BeautifulSoup(text.read(), 'html.parser')   File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\encodings\cp1252.py",
>   line 23, in decode
>       return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0] UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position
>   3565: character maps to

```
   from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
   from termcolor import colored
   import re, os

   import requests
   path = "./brian-work/"
   freddys_library = os.listdir(path)
def getfiles():
  for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
    for file in f:
        if '.html' in file:
            files.append(os.path.join(r, file))
  return files


for book in getfiles():
    print("file is printed")
    print(book)
    text = open(book, "r")
    soup=BeautifulSoup(text.read(), 'html.parser')
    h1 = soup.select('h1')[0].text.strip()
    print(h1)
    if soup.find('h1'):
      h1 = soup.select('h1')[0].text.strip()
    else:

      print ("no h1")
      continue

    filename1=book.split("/")[-1]
    filename1=filename1.split(".")[0]
    print(h1.split(' ', 1)[0])
    print(filename1) 
    if h1.split(' ', 1)[0].lower() == filename1.split('-',1)[0] :
      print('+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++');
      print('same\n');
    else:
      print('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
      print('not')
      count=count+1
```

Please help what should i correct here.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python 3 UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30750843/python-3-unicodedecodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x9d)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is opening a file without knowing its encoding.  The default encoding for `text = open(book, "r")`, per [open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) docs, is the value returned from `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)`, which is `cp1252` for your system.  The file is some other encoding, so it fails.

Use `text = open(book, "rb")` (binary mode) and let BeautifulSoup figure it out.  HTML files usually indicate their encoding.

You can also use `text = open(book,encoding='utf8')` or whatever the correct encoding is if you know it already.

Comment: Thanks buddy, open(book,encoding='utf8') here no need of mode?

Comment: @Mohammed Read is default.