# Trouble loading CSV files

Tags: python, pandas, csv, utf-8

```
import xlrd 
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("/Milk_Papers_Estimated_Class.csv")
path ='/Milk_Papers_Estimated_Class.csv'
```

I experience an error in the following code while trying to run the .csv file.:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 504: invalid continuation byte.
```

I do not know why I am facing this error.Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: try `data = pd.read_csv("/Milk_Papers_Estimated_Class.csv", encoding="latin1")` or other encoding...

Comment: Try this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56453782/utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xe2-invalid-continuation-byte-error

Comment: Pandas assumes the file is utf-8 encoded. This automatically works with ascii/latin1 encodings which is a subset of utf-8 already. But apparently this file has some other encoding, like perhaps utf-16 or a windows code page. Do you know how the file is encoded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the read_csv takes utf-8 as the encoder.

```
data = pd.read_csv("/Milk_Papers_Estimated_Class.csv", encoding='latin-1')
```

Try giving the encoding as latin-1
Might work:")