# Problem when using awsgi "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 10: invalid continuation byte"

Tags: python, laravel, flask, aws-lambda

I have a problem when using AWS Lambda for Flask. I have written a simple program using Flask that decrypts PDF files using PyPDF2. Locally, the program works fine and returns correct results. Unfortunately, after deploying to AWS Lambda, I have an error in the logs:

```
[ERROR] UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 10: invalid continuation byte
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 69, in lambda_handler
    return awsgi.response(app, event, context)
  File "/opt/python/awsgi/__init__.py", line 173, in response
    return sr.response(output)
  File "/opt/python/awsgi/__init__.py", line 95, in response
    rv = super(StartResponse_GW, self).response(output)
  File "/opt/python/awsgi/__init__.py", line 89, in response
    rv.update(self.build_body(headers, output))
  File "/opt/python/awsgi/__init__.py", line 75, in build_body
    converted_output = convert_str(totalbody)
  File "/opt/python/awsgi/__init__.py", line 12, in convert_str
    return s.decode('utf-8') if isinstance(s, bytes) else s
```

I tried the solutions from ['utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 : invalid continuation byte error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56453782/20631212) and the only thing that helped was "changing" utf-8 to ISO-8859-1 in the awsgi/**init**.py file. Unfortunately, the file was decrypted, but I only got two blank pages (the encrypted file actually had two pages). This is a simple function that decrypts a file and returns a temporary NamedTemporaryFile object. then I return the file via send_from_directory.

**SOLVED**

I solved the problem. I replaced send_from_directory with base64, which I then decoded in the laravel application. apparently awsgi cannot return the file in this form

Comment: This sounds like you don't send the request as UTF-8. How do you call the API?

Comment: @JoachimSauer I call the API from my Laravel application. I send the file via Http (attach function) and the password to the file via the post method as data.

Comment: @KJ 
ok, I understand that I should first get the content of the PDF file via "rb" and then save it to a new file via "wb". but how to do it if I add new pages via PdfWriter add_pages? here is a sample of my code

        with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(dir='/tmp', suffix='.pdf', delete=False) as temp_file:
            decrypted_path = temp_file.name
            with open(decrypted_path, "wb") as f:
                for idx in range(len(file.pages)):
                    page = file.pages[idx]
                    out.add_page(page)
                out.write(f)