# cannot replace a Text in a CSV using Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

> I have a CSV file which has two columns 'title' and 'description' . The Description columns has HTML elements . I am trying to replace **'InterviewNotification'** with **InterviewAlert** .

[screenshot here of csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uar6.png)

> This is the code i wrote :

```
text = open("data.csv", "r")
text = ''.join([i for i in text]).replace("InterviewNotification", "InterviewAlert")
x = open("output.csv","w")
x.writelines(text)
x.close()
```

> But, Im getting this Error :

```
      File "C:\Users\Zed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 5786: character maps to <undefined>
```

> Also used pandas , here is the code :

```
dataframe = pd.read_csv("data.csv")  
# using the replace() method 
dataframe.replace(to_replace ="InterviewNotification", value = "InterviewAlert",  inplace = True)
```

> still no Luck. Help pls

Comment: as the raised exception says, you have a UnicodeError. that means your original data is "malformed", i.e. there are char bytes which cannot be decoded with the encoding you're using, which is `UTF` by default. your data is probably not using it, so you should check the original document encoding, then read the file with `open(path, 'rb')` and decode the resulting bytes string with the correct format

Comment: Please do not mark your own question text as citations with the vertical bar in front created by `>` when editing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried specifying the encoding as "utf-8" in your first line? For example:

```
text = open("data.csv", encoding="utf8")
```

It seems that your issue may be related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30750843/python-3-unicodedecodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x9d)

Comment: i did encoding='utf-8-sig' and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You *open* the file but you do not *read* it. To get the text itself do this:

```
textFile = open("data.csv", "r")
text = textFile.read()
textFile.close()
```

Or, to improve the code, use a context manager:

```
with open("data.csv", "r") as textFile:
    text = textFile.read()
```

This ensures that the file is properly closed even if the intermediate code raises an exception.